# MonAgentCore.exe blocked install of SQL Server 2014 SP3 on a Azure VM

Tags: windows-server-2012, azure, sql-server-2014

I've setup a Windows Server 2012 VM with SQL Server 2014.

This service pack is listed in Windows Update for more than a year, but never get installed automatically. If I tried to install it via Windows Update manually, the VM rebooted but the install status is 'Cancelled'.

I then tried to download the SP and run it manually. During install the installer told me that files are used by MonAgentCore.exe would need a reboot after install, but I can't kill the process in Task Manager. It's always respawned once I killed it.

I've searched via Google and someone said it's a Azure VM Extension and can be killed by killing MonAgentLauncher.exe. However I can not find the file in Task Manager.

HOW to temporarily stop this process so I can install the SP without reboot?

Comment: I see you have a support request created and have commented on other forums looking for an answer. I have reached out internally to get additional information.

Comment: I've replied with info needed, internally. ;)
However, I still hope to know if anybody in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else hitting this, try the below steps:

- Close down any open apps on the VM; (we're going to stop it in a bit).
- Open the Azure Portal in your browser: https://portal.azure.com
- Login, enable PIM if required, then navigate to your VM
- Make a note of the settings under `Diagnostic settings`; as these will be dropped later in the process.
- Click `applications and extensions`
- Click `MicrosoftMonitoringAgent` (note: I'm not certain that we need to remove this... but it does no harm)
- Click `Uninstall`
- Click `Microsoft.Insights.VMDiagnosticsSettings` (this one definitely has to go)
- Click `Uninstall`
- On the VM's overview page, click `Stop` to deallocate it (i.e. more than just a reboot, since we've changed the VM's definition).
- Once stopped, click `Start`
- Try installing your SP now; all should work.
- Once you've completed your work, add the previously removed extensions back in and restart the VM again.

  - `MicrosoftMonitoringAgent` should reappear by itself after a while
  - `Microsoft.Insights.VMDiagnosticsSettings` will be added after you reconfigure the `Diagnostic settings` (you should have noted what these were ealier).  Whilst you're there, you may want to check that SQL's checked under `performance counters`.
  - Whilst talking VM Extensions, consider including the [SQL IaaS extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/sql-server-iaas-agent-extension-automate-management?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell) if not already enabled.  Notes on manually installing this can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/sql-agent-extension-manually-register-single-vm?view=azuresql&tabs=bash%2Cazure-cli#azure-portal).

Comment: Side note: I also found this much quicker, though hacky approach - https://expertslab.wordpress.com/2016/07/31/exchange-2010-sp3-upgrade-failed-due-to-monagentcore/ - tldr: rename the offending process' exes to stop them from respawning - but that felt unclean.